# Никак не подхватываются измененные файлы в докере

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

Создал простейший контейнер с NodeJS и Express.

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "forever -w server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.15.3",
        "mongoose": "~4.10.7",
        "body-parser": "~1.17.2",
        "forever": "~0.15.3"
    }
}
```

Как видно, я поставил forever.js для того, чтобы изменения файлов подхватывались автоматически. На хост системе это работает идеально. Далее, я запускаю докер-контейнер, пробросив в него папку с хост-системы:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d -v c:/calendar/code/server:/usr/src/app kamplyktar/test
```

Получаю вот такой лог, вроде ничего критичного:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.0
npm info lifecycle Calendar@0.0.1~prestart: Calendar@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle Calendar@0.0.1~start: Calendar@0.0.1

> Calendar@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app
> forever -w server.js

warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
error: Could not read .foreverignore file.
error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/.foreverignore'
Running on http://localhost:8080
```

Но при изменении server.js на хост-системе, я не вижу никаких изменений по адресу http://localhost:49160/

Т.е. такое ощущение, что forever.js не работает, не перезапускает сервер. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: какая ОС? попробуйте войти в контейнер и поменять файл в нем. что произойдет?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, Win10, менял файл в контейнере - работает как надо, но ведь проблема не в этом =(

Comment: проблема в том, что Windows не уведомляет контейнер об изменении файла. обычно это решают переключением на polling, но forever не позволяет включить эту опцию.